# How to - recursive query in Entity Framework with considerations

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, view, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I want to use recursive query in entity framework so i googled everything and found this :

- Create view and map view to a entity.
- Fire that query directly and retrieve to that entity type.
- Using stored procedure

**Considerations :**

- I am using EF6 Code First approach.
- If I will use view than how to track that view in EF and how to
  migrate it?
- If I use Query for that view, its fine but I trying use object
  oriented approach until necessary.
- If stored procedure is used then how to map it and track it and
  migrate it?
- And which one of the above is better?

Comment: Personally, if you are trying to load a tree until there are either no items left or you load the one you truly want, I would probably temporarily turn on Lazy Loading for this particular call and keep looping until I loaded all the data I needed.  But I'm not sure if that'll be efficient enough.

Comment: I think if i do that then it will fire single queries to fetch records and that would decrease the performance.

Comment: Yeah, if you knew it didn't go to deep, this was a possibility.  But if you don't know the depth, then you wouldn't want to take that approach.  You can use the stored procedure approach and still get the objects to auto map, assuming the fields you select back match up with the entity's property names.

context.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("storedProcedureName",params);